# Increment Array Key in for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

**Background:**  I am reviewing a friends project and I am trying to save him some time by using `for loops` wherever possible in his project. See below an example of what is currently happening (keep in mind there are actually 105 headers I am only using 9 in my example.)

**My Thoughts:** Instead of looping through the returned DB data and assigning those values to variables just to use those same variables in a table directly below it... I want to use the DB array values in the table directly. Also since the inputs in each  increment there names I should be able to do all of this in a loop.

CURRENT LONG FORM CODE:

```
 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pl_bud)){    
            $header_0       = $rows['col_tot_0'];
            $header_1       = $rows['col_tot_1'];
            $header_2       = $rows['col_tot_2'];
            $header_3       = $rows['col_tot_3'];
            $header_4       = $rows['col_tot_4'];
            $header_5       = $rows['col_tot_5'];
            $header_6       = $rows['col_tot_6'];
            $header_7       = $rows['col_tot_7'];
            $header_8       = $rows['col_tot_8'];
            $header_9       = $rows['col_tot_9'];

    echo "<tr>

                    <td><input type='text' name='header_0' value='$header_0'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_1' value='$header_1'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_2' value='$header_2'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_3' value='$header_3'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_4' value='$header_4'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_5' value='$header_5'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_6' value='$header_6'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_7' value='$header_7'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_8' value='$header_8'/></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='header_9' value='$header_9'/></td>
                    </tr>";

        }
```

THIS IS WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACCOMPLISH

```
 while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pl_bud)){  

echo "<tr>";
for($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++){
<td><input type='text' name='header_". $i ."' value='". $rows['col_tot_$i']  ."'/></td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
 }
```

**My Question:** But I am not sure how to correctly increment the `$rows['col_tot_#']`

Comment: Helpful reads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41199224/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/39144966/2943403 just declare and use the `$key`.

Answer (score 2):

`$rows['col_tot_$i']` is just being interpreted as a string literal. Do this instead: `$rows['col_tot_'.$i]`

Comment: That period makes all the difference. Thanks not sure why this gave me such a hard time. lol.